# How does one @import bootstrap.css and @extend bootstrap class selectors?

Tags: css, sass

a backend programmer here.  Just looking at using scss for it's obvious benefit on the front end.

This is what I thought would let me @import bootstrap.css and @extend bootstrap class selectors.  bootstrap.css, and this scss is in same directory as this .scss file

```
// styles.scss
@import "bootstrap.css";
#menu-top {
  @extend .navbar-fixed-top;
}
```

But, I get this

```
// generated styles.css
Error: "\#menu-top" failed to @extend ".navbar-fixed-top".
     The selector ".navbar-fixed-top" was not found.
     Use "@extend .navbar-fixed-top !optional" if the extend should be     
able to fail.
      on line 19 of links_style.scss
Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you're importing the `css` bootstrap version. You must import the `scss` version to export any styles from this.

Comment: Thanks, I went back to Bootstrap, and I'm reading more about scss and Bootstrap, based on your lead here.  Thanks.